# horizontal scrolling level select

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Ok so i have a good chunk of my game finished now and Im working on my level select view. I want to implement a horizontal scroll view with multiple buttons on each view, in something that looks like Angry Birds or Cut The Rope, or something like that. I know I use a scroll view and set anchor points from my reading on here and other sites but im not sure exactly how i can implement that. Im a bit of a noob and my game didnt need to implement any real graphics so im not familiar with open gl or quartz, although im not afraid to try to learn it.

Anyone know how i can implement anchor points in a horizontal scroll view for my level select view?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out the documentation and examples? They're very useful.

Comment: I looked through some and didnt see what i was looking for but any reccomendations would be awesome! Is there one youre thinking of in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already answered, you have to use UIScrollView. We use scroll view when our contents are too large to be shown on the screen.

Refer the class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and Some links that could hep you.

[Apple's scrolling demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html)

[Understanding Scrollview](http://www.lyingonthecovers.net/?p=366)